# SubGrid fetchXML javascript refresh not displaying link-entity column

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a subgrid on a form, that I am trying to refresh with dynamic fetchXML depending on the form data. The fetch is refreshing the subGrid appropiately, however the link-entity columns are either not pulling the data, or the subGrid is not displaying it. Here is my javascript that is running.

```
    function UpdateContactSubGrid() {
    //If this method is called from the Onload, make sure the grid is loaded before proceeding
    if (document.getElementById('new_Opportunity_Contacts_SubGrid') == null) {
        //The subgrid hasn't loaded, wait 1 second and then try again 
        setTimeout(UpdateContactSubGrid, 1000);
        return;
    }    

    // To get the Id of the 'Contacts' subgrid
    var grid = document.getElementById('new_Opportunity_Contacts_SubGrid').control;  

    var fetchXML = "";

    // To get contract lookup from 'CustomerId' field 
    var accountLookup = getAttributeValue("customerid");

    if (accountLookup != null)
    {
         fetchXML = "<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>" +
         "<entity name='new_affiliation'>" +
          "<attribute name='new_role' />" +
          "<attribute name='new_contactid' />" +
          "<attribute name='new_affiliationid' />" +          
           "<order attribute='new_contactid' descending='false' />" +
           "<filter type='and'>" +
            "<condition attribute='statecode' operator='eq' value='0' /> " +
            "<condition attribute='new_clientid' operator='eq' value='" + accountLookup[0].id + "' />" +
           "</filter>" +
           "<link-entity name='contact' from='contactid' to='new_contactid' alias='a_adbe31a68306e2118bc478e3b5100e8d'>" +
           "<attribute name='emailaddress1' />" +
             "<attribute name='telephone1' />" +
             "<attribute name='mobilephone' />" +            
           "</link-entity>" +
         "</entity>" +
       "</fetch>";

    }
    else 
    {
        fetchXML = "<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>" +
         "<entity name='new_affiliation'>" +
          "<attribute name='new_role' />" +
          "<attribute name='new_contactid' />" +
          "<attribute name='new_affiliationid' />" +          
           "<order attribute='new_contactid' descending='false' />" +
           "<filter type='and'>" +
            "<condition attribute='statecode' operator='eq' value='0' /> " +
           "</filter>" +
           "<link-entity name='contact' from='contactid' to='new_contactid' alias='a_adbe31a68306e2118bc478e3b5100e8d'>" +
           "<attribute name='emailaddress1' />" +
             "<attribute name='telephone1' />" +
             "<attribute name='mobilephone' />" +            
           "</link-entity>" +
         "</entity>" +
       "</fetch>";
    }

    if (grid.SetParameter)
        //Inject the new fetchXml
        grid.SetParameter("fetchXml", fetchXML);
    else
        grid.get_innerControl().setParameter("fetchXml", fetchXML);

    //Force the subgrid to refresh
    grid.refresh();
}


// parametrs:
// attributeName: the name of the attribute  
//purpose:
//It checks the existance of the attribute on the form and then get the value of the attriute.It applies null checks.  
function getAttributeValue(attributeName) {
    try {
        var returnValue = null;
        var attrb = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(attributeName);
        if (attrb != null) {
            {
                var attrbValue = attrb.getValue();
                if (attrbValue != null)
                    returnValue = attrbValue;
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
    catch (ex) {
        alert(ex.message + ' ' + ex.name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What’s the relationship type between the entities ? 
With N:N you’ll need to indicate intersect="true" in your link-entity node.
With N:1 you can add link-type="outer" attribute to your link-entity node.

As a side note, consider writing FetchXml dynamically i.e.

```
var fetchXML =
    fetch()
        .entity("new_affiliation")
            .attributes("new_role", "new_contactid", "new_affiliationid")
            .order("new_contactid", fetch.order.Asc)
            .filter()
                .condition("statecode", fetch.op.Equal, 0);

if (accountLookup != null) {
    fetchXML = fetchXML
        .condition("new_clientid", fetch.op.Equal, accountLookup[0].id);
}

fetchXML = fetchXML
    .link({
        entityName: "contact",
        to: "new_contactid",
        from: "contactid",
        alias : "a_adbe31a68306e2118bc478e3b5100e8d",
        type: fetch.link.outer //added outer join
    })
        .attributes("emailaddress1", "telephone1", "mobilephone")

return fetchXML.toString();
```

you can find more about using Dynamic FetchXMl builder on my blog
http://totbcrm.blogspot.com/2014/08/building-fetchxml-dynamically.html

HTH